# Ribbon Button CommandAction doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript

I have two ribbon buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<CustomAction
Id="CustomCustomRibbonTab"
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
RegistrationId="0x01"
RegistrationType="ContentType"
Sequence="100"
>

<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition
      Location="Ribbon.Tabs._children">
      <Tab
        Id="Ribbon.CustomRibbonTab"
        Title="Cotizaciones"
        Description="Manejo de cotizaciones"
        Sequence="501">
        <Scaling
          Id="Ribbon.CustomRibbonTab.Scaling">
          <MaxSize
            Id="Ribbon.CustomRibbonTab.MaxSize"
            GroupId="Ribbon.CustomRibbonTab.ManageCustomGroup"
            Size="OneLargeTwoMedium"/>
          <Scale
            Id="Ribbon.CustomRibbonTab.Scaling.CustomTabScaling"
            GroupId="Ribbon.CustomRibbonTab.ManageCustomGroup"
            Size="OneLargeTwoMedium" />
        </Scaling>
        <Groups Id="Ribbon.CustomRibbonTab.Groups">
          <Group
            Id="Ribbon.CustomRibbonTab.ManageCustomGroup"
            Description="Aceptación o rechazo de cotizaciones enviadas"
            Title="Manejo de cotizaciones"
            Sequence="52"
            Template="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplate">
            <Controls Id="Ribbon.CustomRibbonTab.ManageCustomGroup.Controls">
              <Button
                Id="Ribbon.CustomRibbonTab.ManageCustomGroup.Accept"
                Command="CustomRibbonTab.AprobarCotizacionCommand"
                Sequence="15"
                Image32by32="/_layouts/images/monitor_go.png"
                Description="Cotizaciones aprobadas"
                LabelText="Aprobar cotizaciones seleccionadas"
                TemplateAlias="AC" />
              <Button
               Id="Ribbon.CustomRibbonTab.ManageCustomGroup.Copy"
               Command="CustomRibbonTab.RechazarCotizacionCommand"
               Sequence="19"
               Image32by32="/_layouts/images/monitor_delete.png"
               Description="Negar cotizaciones seleccionadas"
               LabelText="Rechazar cotizaciones seleccionadas"
               TemplateAlias="RC"/>
            </Controls>
          </Group>
        </Groups>
      </Tab>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
      <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplate">
        <Layout
          Title="OneLargeTwoMedium"
          LayoutTitle="OneLargeTwoMedium">
          <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow">
            <Row>
              <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="AC" />
            </Row>
          </Section>
          <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow">
            <Row>
              <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="RC" />
            </Row>
          </Section>
        </Layout>
      </GroupTemplate>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler
      Command="CustomRibbonTab.AprobarCotizacionCommand"
      CommandAction="javascript:MarkItemsFinished();"/>
    <CommandUIHandler
      Command ="CustomRibbonTab.RechazarCotizacionCommand"
      CommandAction="javascript:alert('Cotización rechazada');"/>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
  <CustomAction Id="CustomRibbonTab.AprobarCotizacionCommand.Script"
            Location="ScriptLink"
            ScriptSrc="/_layouts/js/Cuenta.js"/>
</Elements>
```

And have a js file named Cuenta.js, but when I click the first button nothing happens. I checked the name method on js file and is correct. The CustomAction near the end is not taking any of the methods of the js. What can I do about it?. Thank you very much.

Comment: are you using sharepoint 2013 or 2010?

Comment: Sharepoint 2010

Comment: okay, give a try to suggestion answered below by me

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint 2013, you need to use this url to reference layout:

> /_layouts/15/ProjectFolderName/JavaScriptFileName.js

```
<CustomAction Id="CustomRibbonTab.AprobarCotizacionCommand.Script"
            Location="ScriptLink"
            ScriptSrc="/_layouts/15/ProjectFolderName/js/Cuenta.js"/>
```

If you are using SharePoint 2010, you need to use:

```
<CustomAction Id="CustomRibbonTab.AprobarCotizacionCommand.Script"
                Location="ScriptLink"
                ScriptSrc="/_layouts/ProjectFolderName/js/Cuenta.js"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In sharepoint 2010 do I need to add "14" on ScriptSrc line? like this: ScriptSrc="/_layouts/14/ProjectFolderName/js/Cuenta.js"/> Thanks again

Comment: no, you don't need to add "14"

Comment: This is *key* when using a custom ribbon action. Under 2016 a solution will deploy to the /16 hive but a 2016 farm will generally point to the /14 hive (for some things). So the /15 redirect will take you to the /16 hive where things get deployed. Welcome to the mess that is Microsoft.